# Python, SQLAlchemy cascade - save-update

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I would like to ask if it is possible to update the Child records automatically when Parent is changing in a one-to-many relationship.

For example; I have a task list for every project at the company:

```
Project 1 (Parent table)

-> Project 1 - Task1 (Child table) 
-> Project 1 - Task2 
-> Project 1 - Task3 

Project2

-> Project 2 - Task1
-> Project 2 - Task2
-> Project 2 - Task3
```

I want to change the project name from "Project 1" to "Project First" in the Parent table. How can I achieve to update the name of the project in the Child table as well?

Comment: Is the "project name" the primary key in the parent table (and therefore the foreign key in the child table)?

Comment: Hi Gord, The primary key would be an other column, called IDs.

Comment: If the project name is not the primary key (PK) in the parent table then you should *not* be storing it in the child table. Doing so would be what is called "denormalization": (unnecessarily) storing a data element in more than one place. Your child table will have a foreign key that points to the parent table's PK (what you have said is called "IDs") and so queries that need to get the project name should `JOIN` the child table to the parent table and retrieve the project name from the parent table (the only place where it is stored).